# How to restore deleted medias on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, restore

Is there any way/software to restore deleted images&videos files on AWS EC2 server (around 8 GBs data).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recovery methods are the same as with any other server. You can use open-source utilities like [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) or commercial ones like [R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/).

Try snapshot your volume as soon as possible (in case you haven't done that already) and work with volumes created from that snapshot.